# Having Trouble with Parent-to-Child lookup/SOQL Query

Tags: soql, lookup, related-list

I have two objects

Request__c and Matter__c

These two objects have a lookup relationship where Request__c is a lookup field on Matter__c.  So a single Request record can have multiple Matter records.

I’m trying to write a SOQL query on the Request to pull  all Matters associated with each Request.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Status__c, Matter_Type__c FROM Matters__r) FROM Request__c
```

But whenever I try running this I get the following error:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Matters__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I thought that if there was a lookup field on the Matter__c object, then a relationship between  the 2 objects would exist and I could query to pull all the children (Matters) for a given Request.

I’ve checked the field in Setup -> Create -> Objects -> Matter__c and it provides the following information:

Related List Label: Matters

Child Relationship Name: Request

Can someone help me sort this out?

Comment: If `Matters` is a child of `Request__c`, the child relationship name `Request` is a poor choice and now would be the time to change it to `Matters` before you bake it into Apex code.

Comment: oh I totally agree.  I didn't set it up, but inherited it. But it definitely added a couple hours to me scratching my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the API Name of the child relationship as follows via `Execute Anonymous`:

```
for (ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.Request__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == Matter__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
```

Copy this value verbatim and replace `Matters__r`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Status__c, Matter_Type__c FROM Request__r) FROM Request__c
```

Inner query uses the relationship name which you can find on Matters object's lookup field.